# PCA and Gower's Distance

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, distance, gower-similarity

I have a dataset with nutrient information about different ingredients. There are a total of 70 nutrients (numeric features) and 3 categorical features for a total of around 550 ingredients. I am currently using Gower's Distance to calculate the dissimilarity between the ingredients.

Because of high dimensionality as well as incorporation of new features in the future, I wanted to understand if some dimensionality reduction techniques like PCA for the numeric features (or any others as well) would be appropriate for my current usecase?

Comment: What is the purpose of dimensionality reduction? Are you trying to use principle components as predictor(s) in a subsiquent analysis? Or are you doing it for exploratory purposes?

Comment: I will be using them as features for calculating dissimilarity/similarity between the different ingredients. Here, I am using gower's distance since my data is a mix of numeric and categorical features